# Send an outlook email without any permission using python library win32com.client

Tags: python

I need a help. I have automated outlook email using win32com. When I try to send an email automatically, it shows a permission pop up window which I don't want. Can you provide any solution how can I ignore the permission?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQRho.png)

```
import win32com.client as client
outlook = client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
namespace = outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI')
account=namespace.Folders['rpatest@outlook.com']
inbox=account.Folders['Inbox']
message = outlook.CreateItem(0)
message.Display()
message.To ="rpatest1@outlook.com"
message.Subject = "appointment is done"
message.Send()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has an article about why and how to fix the issue [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/security/a-program-is-trying-to-send-an-email-message-on-your-behalf)